# Visual Studio 2017 - Go To Member vs. Go To Symbol

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Can I get a quick reference on the types of results that will be returned by these commands? It is not obvious what `Go to Symbol` actually searches over.

Answer (score 3):

**Go To Type** = hits classes, interfaces, structs, enums and delegates.

**Go To Member** = hits member variables, methods, properties, and consts (so, anything in a class).

**Go To Symbol** = either types or members.

You can also use **Go to All** - the default when entering `ctrl + ,`. This hit files, types, members, and even line numbers. For further reading, see the [docs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/introducing-go-to-the-successor-to-navigate-to/).